# Why shift bits by 8 in Socket Programming - C?

Tags: c, sockets, ip, bit-manipulation

I am studying the FreeBSH Developers Handbook and there I am seeing this code for Socket programming:

```
struct sockaddr_in sa;
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl((((((192 << 8) | 43) << 8) | 244) << 8) | 18);
```

Why is the bitwise shift and or is used here?

I know what bitwise shift and xor is, I made a very small test program:

```
int c = 5;
printb(c);

int d = 5<<2;
printb(d);

int e = d | c;
printb(e);
```

which prints:

```
00000000000000000000000000000101
00000000000000000000000000010100
00000000000000000000000000010101
```

however I do not understand why for sa.sin_addr.s_addr I need to shift the ip and or it with the following value. Can someone explain?

Comment: it is creating a 32 bit argument for `htonl` by using decimal numbers **18** as the lowest 8 bits, **244** as the higher 8 bits (from 9 to 16), **43** as the higher 8 bits (from 17 to 24) and **192** as the higher 8 bits (from 25 to 32)

Comment: @mescalinum Well yes but how? Why xor? Why shift?

Comment: [Sockets Essential](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/sockets-essential-functions.html) May help.

Comment: @KorayTugay, there is no `xor`  (`^`) in your example, you mean `or` (`|`)

Comment: @AlterMann Yes | or..

Comment: @Dayalrai This is already what I am reading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is creating the binary representation for the IP 192.43.244.18.

Let's analyse each operation one by one.

Start from the binary representation of those constants:

```
192 = 11000000
 43 = 00101011
244 = 11110100
 18 = 00010010
```

Innermost operation:

```
(192 << 8) =

= 11000000 << 8 =

= 1100000000000000
```

Next one:

```
(192 << 8) | 43 =

= 1100000000000000 |
          00101011 =

  1100000000101011
```

Next one:

```
((192 << 8) | 43) << 8) =

= 1100000000101011 << 8 =

= 110000000010101100000000
```

Next one:

```
(((192 << 8) | 43) << 8) | 244 =

= 110000000010101100000000 | 244 =

= 110000000010101100000000 |
                  11110100 =

= 110000000010101111110100
```

Next one:

```
(((192 << 8) | 43) << 8) | 244) << 8 =

= 110000000010101111110100 << 8 =

= 11000000001010111111010000000000
```

And finally:

```
(((((192 << 8) | 43) << 8) | 244) << 8) | 18 =

= 11000000001010111111010000000000 | 18 =

= 11000000001010111111010000000000 |
                          00010010 =

= 11000000001010111111010000010010
```

Comment: Ah, I see now.. Thanks. I did not know leftshift added 0's so I could not understand..

Comment: Plus 1 - Quite Well answered.

Comment: @KorayTugay yeah even if I wrote these constants as 8 bits, they are part of a 32 bit integer expression, so you can imagine they **have** the leading zeros :-)

Comment: The decimal value for the final binary is: 3224106002. How is this equal to 192.43.244.18?

Comment: we started from 192.43.244.18 and using the formula (((((192 << 8) | 43) << 8) | 244) << 8) | 18 we obtained 11000000001010111111010000010010, which in decimal is 3224106002 (or did I not understand your question?)

Comment: And now i understand how far i was from being on-topic. Well answered.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by looking at the actual structure of `sock_addr_in` :

```
#include <netinet/in.h>

struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   
    unsigned short   sin_port;    
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     
    char             sin_zero[8];  
};
```

And the struct of `in_addr` :

```
struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr; 
};
```

Now, usually, when we utilisize this s_addr, we write :

```
inet_aton("89.161.169.137", &myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr); //dummy ip
```

OK. How about we check up the inet_aton man ?

> `inet_aton()` converts the Internet host address cp from the IPv4
>   numbers-and-dots notation into binary form **(in network byte order)** and
>   stores it in the structure that inp points to. inet_aton() returns
>   nonzero if the address is valid, zero if not.

Now we clearly know that the `unsigned long s_addr` contains the binary form of the ip in **network byte order**.

You don't need to shift the ip youreslf, instead just use inet_aton() and inet_ntoa() for manipulating ip adresses.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets begin with the binary operations. 
The shift '*a << b*' as you have correctly assumed moves the bits in a by an amount of b in the left direction. Shifting by 1 can be seen as a multiplication by 2. (This is actually how optimization can happen, as a shift operation is faster than multiplication, but most modern compilers take that into account.) 
The or-statement is '*a|b*'. In or, if one of the two elements is 1, the result is 1. This is a standard method used in bitwise operations and actually all the bits inside *a* and *b* are or-ed. E.g.  a = 0010 1011, b = 1111 0000, a|b = 1111 1011.

Now back to the problem. In your case *sa.sin_addr.s_addr* is 0 at the beginning, so when it's or-ed with 192, it adds the bit representation of 192 to the variable. Then it is shifted by 8 bits, in order to free space for the next element in the ip address - each can have values between 0-255, which is exactly 8 bits.  This is then repeated for the rest of the segments.